# Check to Insert or Update table

Tags: php, mysql, database

See the code below, it check if the data exist in the table, if not exist then insert it or else update the table.

As you can see it look a bit messy - is there anyway to improve the code logic or something smaller? I have a few tables that need doing same thing.

```
foreach ($sheet as $data) {
    // Get Phone ID
    $dataPhoneID = mysql_escape_string($data['handset']['phone_id']);

    if (isset($stocks[$dataPhoneID])) {
        $stockPhone = $stocks[$dataPhoneID ];
        $phoneName = mysql_escape_string($stockPhone['description']);
        $stock = mysql_escape_string($stockPhone['stock']);

        $SQL = "SELECT * FROM phone_affiliate WHERE affiliate_id = 1 AND affiliate_phone_id = '$dataPhoneID'";
        $q = mysql_query($SQL);
        if (mysql_num_rows($q) == 0) {
            $SQLInsert = "INSERT INTO phone (name) VALUE('$phoneName')";
            if (mysql_query($SQLInsert)) {
                $phone_id = mysql_insert_id();
                $SQLInsert = "INSERT INTO phone_affiliate (phone_id, affiliate_id, affiliate_phone_id, stock) ";
                $SQLInsert .= "VALUE('$phone_id', '1', '$dataPhoneID', '$stock')";
                mysql_query($SQLInsert) or die(mysql_error());
            }
        } else {
            $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q);
            $phone_id = $row['phone_id'];
            $SQLUpdate = "UPDATE phone_affiliate set stock = '$stock' WHERE affiliate_id = 1 AND phone_id = $phone_id";
             mysql_query($SQLUpdate) or die(mysql_error());
        }

      // Similar code block above for other tables.
    }
}
```

Note: I am aware about PDO but I don't have time to replace it on existing system.

Comment: `mysql_escape_string`? Atleast use `mysql_real_escape_string` (which itself has been deprecated....) use PDO or mysqli, no alternatives. And, relying on deprecated functions means, headaches later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use mysql's [REPLACE INTO](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html) or [INSERT... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).  For example:

```
foreach ($sheet as $data) {
    // Get Phone ID
    $dataPhoneID = mysql_escape_string($data['handset']['phone_id']);

    if (isset($stocks[$dataPhoneID])) {
        $stockPhone = $stocks[$dataPhoneID ];
        $phoneName = mysql_escape_string($stockPhone['description']);
        $stock = mysql_escape_string($stockPhone['stock']);

        $SQLInsert = "INSERT INTO phone_affiliate (affiliate_id, affiliate_phone_id, stock) ";
        $SQLInsert .= "VALUES ('1', '$dataPhoneID', '$stock') ";
        $SQLInsert .= "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE stock = '$stock'";
        mysql_query($SQLInsert);
        if (mysql_insert_id()) {
            $SQLInsert = "INSERT INTO phone (name) VALUE('$phoneName')";
            mysql_query($SQLInsert);
            $phone_id = mysql_insert_id();
            $SQLUpdate = "UPDATE phone_affiliate set phone_id = $phone_id WHERE affiliate_id = 1 AND affiliate_phone_id = $dataPhoneID_id";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Trying to rewrite your example with these statements but I don't know enough about your model, such as unique keys and why you're always inserting into phone if no record exists in phone_affiliate.

Comment: If data does not exist in `phone_affiliate` then it will insert a record into `phone` and `phone_affiliate` tables. If record already exist in `phone_affiliate` then just update it. Do you understand?

Comment: I tried to rewrite your example but it's probably still wrong because I don't know your keys. It's also strange that your WHERE clauses use affiliate_phone_id in one query and phone_id to select in the other.

Comment: Thanks Matt for trying.. `affiliate_phone_id` is a phone id from a retailer and `phone_id` is our internal id. For example CompanyA retailer provide iPhone and they ID is 123, and CompanyB also do Iphone and they ID is 222.  It is strange when looking at the code business logic make sense.

Comment: Does the fields have to be unique? Because I have not set any fields unique keys.

Comment: Yes, for either type of statement you should have a primary key to prevent duplicates.  Even if it's multi-column that's fine.  It's good practice anyway for data integrity.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use     INSERT IGNORE construction