# Update query works but not insert query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having a problem with inserting info into the database. Strangely the update query works but not the insert query. I don't get any error either when submitting, it goes through correctly and echo account saved but nothing is inserted. What am i missing or doing wrong. please assist

```
if(isset($_POST['Submitaccount'])){
$allowedusers = $_POST['users'];
$accountid = trim($_POST['accountid']);
if(!$_POST['copyperms']) $_POST['copyperms']='N';
if(!$_POST['allusers']) $_POST['allusers']='N';
if(!$_POST['enabled']) $_POST['enabled']='N';
if(!$_POST['servertime']) $_POST['servertime']='N';
if(!$_POST['delremovals']) $_POST['delremovals']='N';

unset($_POST['Submitaccount']);
unset($_POST['accountid']);
unset($_POST['users']);

$notmust = array("email" , "skip" , "comments" , "firstmod");

foreach($_POST as $key=>$val){
    if(!trim($val) && !in_array($key , $notmust)) {
        $err = 1;
        $empty = "$key";
        break;
    }
    $qpart .= "`$key` = '".mysql_escape_string($val)."' , " ;
}
if($qpart) $qpart = substr($qpart , 0 , -2);

if(!$err){
    $chk = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * from accounts WHERE name = '".mysql_escape_string($_POST['name'])."' and id <> '$accountid'"));
    if($chk >0){
        $err = 2;
    }
}

if(!$err){
    if(!$accountid){
        $q = "INSERT into accounts SET $qpart ";
        mysql_query($q) or die("Error inserting the record :".mysql_error()."<br>".$q);
        $accountid = mysql_insert_id();
    }else{
        $q = "UPDATE accounts SET $qpart WHERE id = '$accountid'";
        mysql_query($q) or die("Error updating the record :".mysql_error()."<br>".$q);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it work if you execute the `INSERT` query by hand?

Comment: Can you provide a `$qpart` value itself?

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/a/12516294/213550

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have double `if(!$err){`. Do you want both `(!$err)` into one? If the first `(!$err)` is for indicator for the second to insert, function **SELECT** can not be placed above the function **INSERT** *indirectly*.

try this:

```
if(!$err){
    $chk = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * from accounts WHERE name = '".mysql_escape_string($_POST['name'])."' and id <> '$accountid'"));
    if($chk >0){
        $err = 2;
        // if(!$err){ again ...
        if(!$accountid){
            $q = "INSERT into accounts SET (column1) VALUES ($var1)";
            mysql_query($q) or die("Error inserting the record :".mysql_error()."<br>".$q);
            $accountid = mysql_insert_id();
            }
        else{
            $q = "UPDATE accounts SET $qpart WHERE id = '$accountid'";
            mysql_query($q) or die("Error updating the record :".mysql_error()."<br>".$q);
            }
        }
}
else{
    //other code to handle if ($err)
}
```

Note: I would prefer using PDO to handle database, it's so simple scripting, besides, it's no longer supported

Comment: I have tried your suggestion but the result stays the same. nothing is inserted.

Comment: change the $qpart into (column1,...) VALUES ($variable)

Comment: this is what i have tried but still no result. $q = "INSERT INTO users (name, username, password)\n" . "VALUES (\'$name\', \'$username\', \'$pass\')\n" . "\n"  . "";

Comment: do the variables in ($) already represent each of them correctly.?

Answer (score 3):

This is because the `INSERT` command has different syntax:

```
INSERT into accounts SET $qpart "
```

is not usual, you can write it like this:

```
INSERT into accounts (column names) VALUES your values"
```

> [13.2.5 INSERT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand that mysql functions have become deprecated. Either using mysqli or pdo would be the better option, but if you absolutely have to use mysql as a solution i would suggest not posting the form to itself, rather post to another php file as you will have less problems.In my environment it seems to work well as an interim solution while we are rewriting everything to use mysqli.If it a go and let me know.

Comment: Thanks that did it. I was actually pleasantly surprised as i was hitting a brick wall with a hole lot of experimentation. I just created another php file with just posting 3 variables and low and behold it inserted to the database. Thanks again.